# Getting errors with Parameterized Update Sub

Tags: t-sql, asp.net-4.0, vb.net-2010

No idea why this isn't working.

I have a simple form with some text boxes and drop down lists.  It displays the profile of an employee.  Users should be able to manually edit the fields and click Save.  When they click save I keep getting errors.

Q1: How can I handle inserting Null values for SmallDateTime data types?

Q2: What am I doing wrong with the TinyInt (SqlServer 2005) on the JobGrade?

```
Option Explicit On 
Imports System 
Imports System.Data 
Imports System.Data.SqlClient 

Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim sqlJobsDB As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("JobsDB").ConnectionString)
    Dim sqlCmdUpdate As SqlCommand = sqlJobsDB.CreateCommand()

    Try

        sqlJobsDB.Open()
        sqlCmdUpdate.CommandText = _
            "UPDATE tblEmployee " + _
             "SET Firstname = @Firstname, LastName = @LastName, HiredLastName = @HiredLastName, " + _
                "DateHired = @DateHired, Role = @Role, CADate = @CADate, CAType = @CAType, " + _
                "JobDate = @JobDate, JobGrade = @JobGrade " + _
             "WHERE EUID = '" & Session("sProfileEUID") & "';"

        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@HiredLastName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@DateHired", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Role", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@CADate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@CAType", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@JobDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@JobGrade", SqlDbType.TinyInt)

        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@FirstName").Value = txtFirstName.Text
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@LastName").Value = txtLastName.Text
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@HiredLastName").Value = txtHiredLastName.Text
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@DateHired").Value = txtDateHired.Text
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@Role").Value = ddlRole.SelectedValue.ToString

        If txtCADate.Text = "" Then
            sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@CADate").Value = 0
        Else
            sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@CADate").Value = txtCADate.Text
        End If

        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@CAType").Value = ddlCAType.SelectedValue

        If txtJobDate.Text = "" Then
            sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@JobDate").Value = 0
        Else
            sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@JobDate").Value = txtJobDate.Text
        End If

        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@JobGrade").Value = CByte(txtJobGrade.Text)

        sqlCmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception

        'Debugging
        lblErrMsg.Text = ex.ToString
        lblErrMsg.Visible = True

    Finally

        sqlJobsDB.Close()

    End Try

End Sub</code>
```

I open the form and fill it out correctly.
I'll enter something like "4" (no quotes) for JobGrade.  It still says "conversion from strink ''" like its not even seeing when I input items on the form.

Errors are below:

System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "" to type 'Byte' is not valid. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToByte(String Value) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToByte(String Value) at Profile.btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in

**Update**

The DBNull.Value issue is resolved.
The JobGrade, and Role are still issues.  When throwing up some breakpoints on it doens't fetch the contents of the textbox or the dropdown list.

** Updated Code **

```
Protected Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click

    Session("sProfileEUID") = Nothing
    Response.Redirect("~/Management/EditUsers.aspx")

End Sub

Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim sqlJobsDB As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("JobsDB").ConnectionString)
    Dim sqlCmdUpdate As SqlCommand = sqlJobsDB.CreateCommand()

    Try

        sqlJobsDB.Open()
        sqlCmdUpdate.CommandText = _
            "UPDATE tblEmployee " + _
             "SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName, HiredLastName = @HiredLastName, " + _
                "DateHired = @DateHired, Role = @Role, CADate = @CADate, CAType = @CAType, " + _
                "JobDate = @JobDate, JobGrade = @JobGrade " + _
             "WHERE EUID = '" & Session("sProfileEUID") & "';"

        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@HiredLastName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@DateHired", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Role", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@CADate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@CAType", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@JobDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@JobGrade", SqlDbType.TinyInt)

        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@FirstName").Value = txtFirstName.Text
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@LastName").Value = txtLastName.Text
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@HiredLastName").Value = txtHiredLastName.Text
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@DateHired").Value = txtDateHired.Text
        sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@Role").Value = ddlRole.SelectedValue.ToString

        If txtCADate.Text <> "" Then sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@CADate").Value = CDate(txtCADate.Text)
        If txtCADate.Text = "" Then sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@CADate").Value = DBNull.Value

        If ddlCAType.Text <> "" Then sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@CAType").Value = ddlCAType.SelectedValue
        If ddlCAType.Text = "" Then sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@CAType").Value = DBNull.Value

        If txtJobDate.Text <> "" Then sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@JobDate").Value = CDate(txtJobDate.Text)
        If txtJobDate.Text = "" Then sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@JobDate").Value = DBNull.Value

        If txtJobGrade.Text <> "" Then sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@JobGrade").Value = CInt(txtJobGrade.Text)
        If txtJobGrade.Text = "" Then sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@JobGrade").Value = DBNull.Value

        sqlCmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception

        lblErrMsg.Text = ex.ToString
        lblErrMsg.Visible = True

    Finally

        sqlJobsDB.Close()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Edit 2:

So I've pretty much given up on this, and instead moved the table into an FormView ItemTemplate, with an EditTemplate also.  I modified it as described in the following link.  http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/FormView-Control.aspx

Comment: Please confirm that you aren't resetting the values of the textboxes to nothing in the Page_Load event implementation because if you enter a 4 into Textbox1 then CINT(Textbox1.Text) will work.

Comment: @NoAlias That might be the case, however I can successfully update the two dates on the form for "@CADate" and "@JobDate", however after inputting a date I can't remove it using DBNull.Value.  I open up SQL server 2005 and I can write the update statement and it works fine... no idea why this is so difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: Make sure the table structure allows nulls and set the parameter value to DBNull.Value.

Q2:

```
If IsNumeric(txtJobGrade.Text) Then

sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@JobGrade").Value = CInt(txtJobGrade.Text) 

Else

sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@JobGrade").Value = 0 'Or Default Value

End If
```

You can always make that a drop down list to prevent open ended data input.

Comment: Q1:  If I use something like `If txtCADate.Text = "" Then sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@CADate").Value.IsDBNull()` it throws a Null reference exception even though the table in the database is configured to accept nulls.  Using `sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters("@CADate").Value = DBNull` does not work.

Comment: IsDBNull() is a method that tells you whether or not the value for the parameter is null.  Try .Value = DBNull.Value and see if that helps.

Comment: Oh I see, I read your initial comment wrong.
- New problem, on the form if I Delete everything out of the textbox it should feed DBNull.Value into the Database during the Update statement, but it fails and refreshes the screen giving me no error message.

Comment: Do you explicitly set it to DBNull.Value when the textbox is empty or just assume?  Also, you could step through it with breakpoints to get the error message.

Comment: Everywhere in my original post where the If/Then forks and I assign the value of "0" to something is where "DBNull.Value" is now.  I'm walking through it with breakpoints now, thanks.

Comment: No problem.  Edit the question or post more comments if you run into more issues.  I'll check back in a little later.

Comment: I've updated the main post, the issue I'm having now is when using the DBNull.Value method, I can't actually insert a null value into the Database.  The Cint() solution still doensn't work, it's telling me you can't convert from a string to Int32 when I input something like a 4.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little odd to see how you're done the parameters.  Typically, I'd expect to see something more along these lines:

```
With sqlCmdUpdate.Parameters
   .clear()
   .addWithValue("@parm1", mytextbox1.text)
   .addWithValue("@parm2", mytextbox2.text)
End With
```

For one, `.add` has been deprecated -- still works, but some issues to be aware of (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx).

Secondly, it's always best to call `.clear()`.

Also -- you might think about a more standard approach to checking for values -- for example:

```
If txtJobGrade.Text <> "" Then...
```

Would be better written as

```
If NOT string.isnullorempty(me.txtJobGrade.text) Then...
```

Try making a few of those changes, and see what (if any) errors you're still getting.

Comment: I appreciate all the pointers.  It will be a few days before I have time to really dig into this again but I'll let you know how it goes.